# Extremely slow operation when loading 1,440,000 size ArrayList with Android

Tags: android, arraylist

Source code is as shown below

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> readFile(String fileName) {

String sdPath;
sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
ArrayList<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();

try {

Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File(sdPath + fileName)));

while( s.hasNext() ) {
data.add( s.nextInt() );
}
}
catch(FileNotFoundException fN) {
fN.printStackTrace();
}
catch(IOException e) {
System.out.println(e);
}

return data;    
}
```

When I run this code, LogCat shows below message with any display change in my android

```
.
.
.
04-27 00:12:31.216: D/dalvikvm(17141): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1953K, 23% free 15699K/20295K, paused 2ms+12ms
.
.
.
```

Moreover, the above code is fully operable in my desktop within few second..

plz help me.

Comment: Can you give us more details? What exactly is the problem you're looking to solve?  The title says slow operation - are you trying to speed it up?  What does "fully operable" mean? If you're seeing the Garbage Collector firing off a lot (The GC_CONCURRENT line), chances are good there's a memory being allocated in a loop.  Eclipse DDMS has a view called "Allocations" that might be helpful.  http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/track-mem.html

Answer (score 2):

Phones have very limited resources compared to desktop computers. You should not expect that a phone be able to complete a computationally intense task at the same speed as a desktop computer...

You are using up all of the phones RAM trying to load that large of an ArrayList into it.

a few tips:

- Move your readFile code to a background thread if it isn't there already.
- Consider a different data structure some kind of SQL would probably handle this large of a data set more effeciently
- Consider loading only a (relatively) small portion of the ArrayList at a time. do work on the section you need, and when you need another section load it seperately.
- Consider breaking up your data into multiple smaller files and load only the one that you need for the current operation.

Comment: Thank you. My data contains terrain elevations for each arrays. Like 112, 114, 119, 1023, .... the total file size is only 5 to 6Mb. Therefore, even though phones have very limited resources, it should be loaded into the phones memory I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the data on disk and use memory mapped IO instead. Take a look at [FileChannel and the map function](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29) and take it from there. The buffer classes have [methods to retrieve integers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt%28int%29) as well.